# apply css to a <img> after flush(); ob_flush(); function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pulling a lot of data from mysql database that takes more than 10 minutes to complete running,  I'm trying to add some visual to my application so while the script is running I'm displaying a loading image gif.

```
<img id="dvLoading" alt="src="/img/loadingpage.gif" 
onload="hideload()"/>
```

my script is two part, I put these two `php` function `flush(); ob_flush();` to display the data from the buffer when the first part is done and move to run the second part.
So after the second part is done I want to hide the image by javascript code

```
<script>
function hideload(){
  document.getElementById('dvLoading').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

the thing is that when I put the JavaScript code before calling the php function `flush()`
it works and it hide the image, but when I put the javascript code after `flush()` the java script function it doesn't work.

I will use use `fadeout()` function if I knew exactly how long the script take, but it depend a the user selections.

Any suggestions or thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just skip the function all together and put `this.display='none'` directly in the `onload` argument. It may contain any JavaScript code which should be executed instantly after the page is completely loaded. Example:

```
<body onload="hideload();">
```

The reason `hideload()` failed to be called is because it didnt exist when the page was done loading (it was not yet parsed by the javascript runtime, at least)

**edit:**
Approved of @mongotops edit because he already accepted it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you so mcuh for the insight!! do you have any idea how to prevent that? or some work around it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a method, why can't it be on the page always? Or just hide it with `this.display='none'` like I wrote.

Comment: it's a gif image that keep turning something like http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading45.gif&imgrefurl=http://jimpunk.net/Loading/?page_id%3D9&h=400&w=550&sz=16&tbnid=Js6066J_8z_CZM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=124&zoom=1&usg=__U5PHhklKVjbpy7rreUXcFzsTTn0=&docid=yfJFhdPmJGN68M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kusTUcihE42xqwHOo4CYCA&ved=0CEIQ9QEwBA&dur=1770 

I want to hide it when the script is over.

Comment: because of your insights, I found the solution, I will edit you answer. Thank you so much hank!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you hide it on load event, when a far better approach is to initialize default CSS option.

Like this

```
<div id="dvLoading" style="display:none;">
 <img  src="/img/loadingpage.gif" />
</div>
```

It's faster and more clean. And you don't need PHP for this.
You shouldn't really mix JavaScript and PHP responsibilities.

In jquery-ajax you can handle this way:

```
$.ajax({

   beforeSend: function(){
     $("#dvloading").show(100);
   },
   complete : function(){
     $("#dvloading").hide(100);
   }
});
```

Comment: Your solution is great!! and I just learn two jquery-ajax functions!! Thank you so much!!!